# Comparing complicated lists

Tags: python, list, duplicates

So I've got a function in python that has a list containing lists and I'm trying to compare the contents of the list to see if I have a duplicate within it, and then return True if there are duplicates.  Essentially something like this;

```
def dupCheck():
    aList = ([3.3,3.2], [1,1], [3.3,3.2], [7,7])
    if duplicates in aList:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: There is like 6 questions existing about this subject in SO and codereview. You should search before asking.

Comment: Ok that is a nice (broken) function. I'm not sure exactly what you expect us to do since **you didn't actually ask a question.**

Answer (score 4):

You can do it lazily, returning True on the first duplicate in place of creating a whole set first:

```
def dup_check(lst):
    seen = set()
    for tup in map(tuple, lst):
        if tup in seen:
            return True
        seen.add(tup)
    return False
```

To keep lazy evaluation you should use *itertools.imap* in place of *map* using python2.

If you want a close to one liner solution, you could take advantage of the fact the *set.add* returns None and combine with *any*:

```
def dup_check(lst):
    seen = set()
    return any(tup in seen or seen.add(tup) for tup in map(tuple, lst))
```

`seen.add(tup)` is always going to be *None* and only if we have already added an identical tuple will *tup in seen* return True so *any* will either short-circuit on the first dupe or return False if there are no dupes.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when checking whether a list has duplicates, you would just create a `set` from the list, thus removing the duplicates, and then compare the size of that set to the size of the original list. In this case this is not possible, as the nested lists are not hashable and can thus not be added to a set. However, if you always have a list of lists (and not, e.g. a list of lists and other things, or a list of lists of lists) then you can convert the sublists to tuples before putting them into the set.

```
>>> def dupCheck(lst):
...     return len(set(tuple(l) for l in lst)) != len(lst)  # duplicates -> true
...    
>>> dupCheck([[3.3,3.2], [1,1], [3.3,3.2], [7,7]])
True
```

Comment: Totally pythonic way of doing it!

Comment: Question: This is a neat solution, but it will touch ever element in the list. Wouldn't a more efficient solution be to build a set of `seen`. Loop through the elements, if element in seen, return True, else seen.add(element). After loop, return False...

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the list of list problem:

```
def remove_doubles(a):
    """Removes list doubles in list where list(set(a)) will raise a TypeError."""
    clean_list = []
    for b in a:
        if b not in clean_list:
            clean_list += [b]
    return clean_list
```